# Modifying I/O Data in Python

Tags: python, string, replace

(Python 3.5) Is there a way to change an letter (from user input) into a different letter? This would work like an encryption program. The user would write, "Hello" and the program would print, "Gwkki."

```
H = "G"
e = "w"
l = "k"
o = "i"
q = input("Message: ")
print (q[0:4])
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack overflow. Yes. You could e.g. use a caesar cipher, where you shift all letters by a given number of steps in the alphabet.  Google that and you'll find examples. You'd assign the 'hello' to a string, then step through the string with e.g. a for loop to apply your cipher by attaching the shifted character to an empty string, one after another.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

yes you can simply use `str.translate` like this

```
text = input('Enter your text: ')

_in = "helo"
out = "Gwki"

print(text.translate(text.maketrans(_in, out)))
```

just like the name says, it "translates"(substitutes) each letter from your text found in your text in `_in` to the corresponding value in `out`

Answer (score 0):

If you have a set way to convert the letters you could easily make a conversion function that you will pass the input in and it'll convert to necessary letters and return it.

Ex:

Hello passed into a function becomes Gwkki
Olleh will become ikkwg and so on.

Answer (score 0):

Say that the input string is stored in `inputs` and that you want to encode it without builtins and string methods?

```
transl = {'a':'W', ...}
encryp = ''
for e in (transl[c] for c in inputs): encryp += e
```

If a string method (not applied directly to `inputs`) is allowed

```
transl = {'a':'W', ...}
encryp = ''.join(transl[c] for c in inputs)
```

In both cases we use a `dict` to do the translation, constructing a sequence of encoded characters; to join these characters we can use a `for` loop and string concatenation (the `+` operator) or, in more idiomatic and efficient way, join them using the null string and its method `.join()`

---

Of course, the right way to proceed is using `.translate()`, as shown in [danidee's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36819728/2749397).